# Silverlight - RIA Services Data/Service issue

Tags: silverlight-3.0, wcf-ria-services

I have a baffling situation, which maybe you guys can help.
My RIA Solution does not retrieve the data from the service...

To give you an idea...
My domain service is derived from LinqToSqlDomainService and is in a Web Application project.

I had first created a RIA Services project with MVC and the Get query to the service (DomainContext) works great.

I then created a new RIA Solution, and used a Web Application project (instead of MVC to host the service), and this just does not get the data.

The Silverlight (RIA) client project is a copy of the working one and although I changed references, etc., I suspect there could be a problem in this project, either creating the HttpDomainClient:
    this(new HttpDomainClient(new Uri("DataService.axd/FooAdmin-Web-FooDomainService/", System.UriKind.Relative)))

or in the LoadOperation:
    loadOp = this._context.Load(this._context.GetFooQuery());

What are some ways, I can troubleshoot this and see what is failing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see the HTTP requests and possibly error codes.